# Javadoc external referenced classes using gradle in ItelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, hyperlink, javadoc

In my Java project in IntelliJ, I'm trying to add in my javadoc some links to external referenced classes, like class `Object`.

My javadoc is:
[my method equal() javadoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otOjw.png)
generated with the code:

```
 /**
 * Checks if the {@link java.lang.Object} is equal to the input one.
 * @param o The object to be confronted with.
 * @return true if this {@link Object} is equal to the input {@link Object}, false otherwise.
 * @see #hashCode()
 */
```

while I would like it to be like the one of the class [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):
[method equal() in HashMap javadoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l8L8.png)
with the links to the documentation of `equals()` of the class `Object` and all the links to the class `Object` itself ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)) active and working.

The Reference Guide of javadoc at this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html) says

> External referenced classes can be linked to using the -link and -linkoffline options.

I'm using **gradle**, not the terminal, and I don't know how to add this option.

Thanks a lot in advance to anyone who helps me solve this! :)